# How to update a plugiun using info in Developer's Log?

Tags: ee, developer-log, title-master

I am getting several messages in my Developer's Log similar to this. It wants me to update a plugin.

```
Deprecated function set_variable() called in system/expressionengine
/third_party/title_master/mcp.title_master.php on line 138.
Deprecated since 2.6. Use view-><var> = <value>; instead.
```

Below is what the above is referring to, but I am not sure what to change it to.

```
public function settings()
{
    $this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', 
                            lang('channel_settings_page'));
```

Can someone tell me exactly what it should be? Would help me a lot and I thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [the add-on](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master) has been discontinued, so doubt the developer will (or has) updated. The change in question happened in v2.6 of ExpressionEngine. You've not specified what version of EE you're using.

Change this line:

```
$this->EE->cp->set_variable('cp_page_title', 
                            lang('channel_settings_page'));
```

To this:

```
ee()->view->cp_page_title = lang('channel_settings_page');
```

Comment: Yes the plugin had been abandoned. EE v2.7.2 Thanks for your help!